# Today panel is white/disabled and unusable since upgrading to Sierra

Tags: macos, notifications

The right side panel for me, is white and disabled. I do not see any settings that would cause this behaviour. How can I return to the working version of this panel? In particular, the World Clock widget is important to me and I currently can't use it.

[image: notifications panel is white and disabled]

Comment: Have you tried removing the widgets and adding them again (see https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25142 for more information on how to do it)?

Comment: I did. Just tried again for good measure and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has resolved itself. Apparently the solution is to wait.